# html page annotator

Tags: c#, javascript, python, html-parsing, data-annotations

I have to write a web page annotator.
And my requirements are the following:

1) given a set of pages, I want to annotate them efficiently (in a browser, in an external application that knows how to render HTML, etc.)

2) I select (highlight, make active) manually a string of text, and dropdown menu appears that allows to select from a set of options

3) after that the iterator appears (like in a browser when pressed ctrl+F to search) and I want to be able to navigate through matches of the string, selected in the previous step, on the same page

4) comparison function on strings is given that has interface: given two strings it outputs either 1 or 0, depending on strings match

5) when I press iterator button, i move to the next match for selected string, and then a message box should appear (or any other thing where i can confirm that it is a true match)

6) having confirmed that it is a true match, the text of a page should be modified such that current match became surrounded by special tag
(for instance <<< optionX >>> matched text <<< /optionX >>> ), where optionX is defined based on a value selected in the first step (dropdown menu)

5) when all matches (defined by comparison function) are found on a page, I would like to mark another string of text on the same page and then repeat the process, by finding all the matches, confirming some of them, and modifying page source correspondingly

6) then a modified page should be stored on a local drive

QUESTIONS:
Can you please suggest what is the right tool to do that?

1)Is it OK to use javascript and work in a browser. If yes, what methods are required for that and are there any useful libraries that do just that, or at least cover some functionality described above

2) May be is it better to build a custom desktop app, that renders a page in a special frame, and have appropriate buttons to navigate, confirm etc. (python or C# are considered), and again what classes and libraries can help

[UPDATE]:

I know how to work with the content of a page, but I am curious how to make it comfortable for annotators to use, how to build the right dialog with the user: ways to have all candies such as dropdown menus and iterator that is visible for users, dialog for confirmation etc.

The goal is to annotate a lot of pages with that, therefore interface should be efficient. I am a researcher (and this is not a homework as you might think, i just described what is needed in a formal way ) and I have only poor experience writing user oriented apps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did u try anything yet??

Comment: hi, Neal, this is not a homework. I just want to get it done optimally and that's why I am asking to propose the right approach. I understand that this is for sure not a rocket science at all

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a web browsers job. You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to search and modify a html page. This example will find all  occurrences of `homework` and change the text to `<< homework >>`

```
$("*").each(function () { 
  if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('homework','<< homework >>')); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: cander, thanks for your reply. though may be should focus the question a little bit more. I know how to work with the content of a page, but I am curious how to make it comfortable for annotators to use, question on how to build the right dialog with the user: ways to have all candies such as dropdown menues and iterator that is visible for users, etc. The goal is to annotate a lot of pages with that, therefore interface should be efficient. I am a researcher and that's and I have only poor experience writing user oriented apps. thank you

Comment: sorry, that was a little harsh with the whole 'homework' thing. I would suggest taking a look at [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com). In order to maintain the content of the pages you're annotating i'd write all your user interface stuff in javascript, perhaps using a master jquery ui dialog `$('<div> ....all my text annotating tools </div>').dialog()` to do all your page editing and annotating. This way you can have a save operation that runs after the dialog is closed and removed from the page, so you could do a simple `$.post('/mypagesavingservice', { html: $('html') }) to save the edited page

Comment: cander, thank you for the expanded version. Will try to hack out smth.